# What kind of game is Flappy Bird/Swing Copters?

Tags: terminology

The games [Flappy Bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flappy_Bird) and [Swing Copters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Copters), both created by Dong Ngyuyen, have very similar play mechanics.  Both require the player to navigate a character through gaps in walls, and require very little else, scoring mainly by how far the player can go before an inevitable crash as the player character automatically scrolls through the game.

Other games have similar game mechanics: [Jetpack Joyride](http://halfbrick.com/our-games/jetpack-joyride/) is a similar game, and other short ios and flash games follow a similar style of play - seeing how long a player can persevere in a level that automatically scrolls.

What is the name or genre for this type of wall-avoiding game that seems so prolific in short ios/flash games like these?

Comment: Side scrolling platformer?

Comment: @TZHX It's definitely not a platformer. The character is explicitly not supposed to land anywhere, including the platforms.

Comment: That just depends on your interpretation of platforms.

Comment: It also just occured to me that auto-scrolling is a major element of this type of game, so I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term/genre is known as an [Endless Runner](http://www.giantbomb.com/endless-runner/3015-7179/) or [Endless Flyer](http://iphone.qualityindex.com/charts/18648/endless-flyers-on-iphone). Endless games are defined by just that... They keep going indefinitely until you inevitably lose, either by ramping up difficulty the longer you go like Jetpack Joyride or just being difficult from the start like Flappy Bird and Swing Copters.

Comment: So this would also apply to a 3D version of such a game, like Temple Run?  Or auto-racing games like Race the Sun?

Comment: yes it does. You are still progressing endlessly.

Comment: 3D versions of the same genre are just that, 3D versions of the same genre. I would also consider Brainpipe and TEC 3001 to fit into that category. Also note that such games are not always endless, or may have an endless mode and a non-endless mode, so I generally just refer to the combined genre as "runner".

Comment: The genre is sometimes referred to as "Auto-Runner", too.

Comment: Weird to think that the original Donkey Kong game is an endless runner.

Comment: @Batophobia, Donkey Kong may be endless, but it isn't a "runner" - you don't automatically run forward at a more-or-less-fixed speed while dodging obstacles. Donkey Kong is a platformer, like (Super) Mario Brothers: you choose when to stay still, when to run, when to climb, when to jump, and in what direction.